# Login into Azure app service running instance

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-app-service-plans, azure-vm-scale-set

I am having an Azure app service plan running. I need to login into the instance to create ssh key.

In the Azure portal, they provided the ssh option to login but it's not working for me, It ends up with error message like **SSH CONNECTION CLOSE - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED x.x.x.x:28160.**

How do I enable ssh and login into the service plan running instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I enable ssh and login into the service plan running instance?

If you want to ssh into the Web App, not the service plan, you need to use the image that enabled the SSH, for example, the runtime stack **Node 10.14** that Azure provided. When the Web App is OK, the ssh connection shows like below:

[image]

Or you can create a custom image as you want and enable the SSH inside it. The steps in [Configure SSH in a custom container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#enable-ssh).

Comment: @AnbarasuSubramaniyan So you use the Azure Function, not the Web app and want to connect to the VM inside the function?

Comment: I am created Azure function with python platform and deployed in the app service plan. now I need to communicate with another Azure VM from azure function to check particular directory residing in VM. for that I created ssh connection from Azure function using the username and password. this is working in expected manner. 

But I am looking for the way to login without username and password.for that I planned to use ssh passwordless authentication. But I couldn't accomplish that. 

do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: @AnbarasuSubramaniyan So you need to change the VM authentication into the SSH public key and then use it in the function.

Comment: @AnbarasuSubramaniyan Well, if it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @AnbarasuSubramaniyan So what about the result? Does it solve your problem?